# React: updating state after deletion

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to update elements after deletion, without refreshing a page. Currently, if delete a record, need to refresh a page to see the result. As I understand, need to update `useState`, but I do not understand how to do it. If I loop `useEffect` it works but slowly, but I think it's not the best idea to loop `get` response.

1. Get all records from a database.

```
const PostsGetUtill = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        axios.get("api/v1.0/post/get").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setPosts(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, []);           //  }, [fetchPosts]); <--- working well with loop 

    return (
        <section className="container-post">
            <PostMansonry posts={posts} columns={3} />
        </section>
    );
};

export default PostsGetUtill;
```

2. Sort and map records

```
export default function PostMansonry({ posts, columns }) {
    return (
        <section className="masonry" style={{ gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${columns}, minmax(275px, 1fr))` }}>
            {posts.sort((a, b) => a.zonedDateTime < b.zonedDateTime ? 1 : -1).map((posts, index) =>
                <MasonryPost {...{ posts, index, key: index }} />)
            }
        </section>
    )

}
```

3. Put data to the card

```
export default function MasonryPost({ posts, index }) {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="masonry-post">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{posts.title}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{posts.description}</p>
                    <p className="card-text"><small className="text-muted"> {posts.zonedDateTime}</small></p>
                    <div><button type="button" onClick={(e) => PostsDeleteUtill(posts.post_Id)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

4. Deleting

```
const PostsDeleteUtill = async (post_Id) => {
    axios.delete(`api/v1.0/post/delete/${post_Id}`).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.log(error.request);
        } else {
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log('error config', error.config);
    });
};

export default PostsDeleteUtill;
```

Comment: The best thing would be to use some state management library like Redux, because `delete` component is too deep, you cant pass delete function that much deep(technically you can, but its not very convenient). So make global prop `posts` and use `dispatch` to fetch new posts from `delete` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is, in your `PostsDeleteUtill` function, in the promise return of your `axios.delete`, you need to update your `posts` state, which is set in `PostsGetUtill`.

In order to do that, you have 2 options:

1. Use a global state (React Context, Redux, etc)
2. Pass your `setPosts` handle all the way to your `PostsDeleteUtill`

I think option 1 is a bit cleaner for your specific case, but if you don't need global state anywhere else in your project, maybe it is fine to have a not so clean solution instead of implementing the whole global state structure for only one thing.

### Option 1 pseudo code:

Your `PostsGetUtill` component would use a global state instead of local state:

```
const PostsGetUtill = () => {
    // Remove this:
    // const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        axios.get("api/v1.0/post/get").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            // Instead of a local "setPosts" you would have a global
            // "setPosts" (in Redux, this would be a dispatch)
            dispatch({type: "PUT_POSTS", action: response.data})
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // No changes here...
        });
    };

    // This runs only the first time you load this component
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, []); 

    // Use your global state here as well:
    return (
        <section className="container-post">
            <PostMansonry posts={globalState.posts} columns={3} />
        </section>
    );
};

export default PostsGetUtill;
```

In your `PostsDeleteUtill` function:

```
const PostsDeleteUtill = async (post_Id) => {
    axios.delete(`api/v1.0/post/delete/${post_Id}`).then(response => {
        // Update global state here. Probably filter the data to remove
        // the deleted record
        const updatedPosts = globalState.posts.filter(post => post.id !== response.data.id)
    }).catch((error) => {
      // No changes here
    });
};

export default PostsDeleteUtill;
```

---

### Option 2 pseudo code:

In your `PostsGetUtill` component, create and pass on a `handleRemovePost`:

```
// Your existing code ...
const handleRemovePost = (postID) => {
    const filteredPosts = posts.filter(post => post.id !=== postID)
    setPosts(filteredPosts)
}

return (
    <section className="container-post">
        <PostMansonry posts={posts} columns={3} handleRemovePost={handleRemovePost} />
    </section>
);
```

In your `PostMansonry`, pass on again your `handleRemovePost`

```
export default function PostMansonry({ posts, columns, handleRemovePost }) {
    return (
        // Your existing code ...
        <MasonryPost {...{ posts, index, key: index, handleRemovePost }} />)
    )
}
```

Again in your `MasonryPost`

```
export default function MasonryPost({ posts, index, handleRemovePost }) {
    return (
        // Your existing code ...
        <button type="button" onClick={(e) => PostsDeleteUtill(posts.post_Id, handleRemovePost)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    )
}
```

And finally:

```
const PostsDeleteUtill = async (post_Id, handleRemovePost) => {
    axios.delete(`api/v1.0/post/delete/${post_Id}`).then(response => {
        handleRemovePost(response);
    })
};
```

---

PS: Please note that I only added a pseudo-code as a reference, trying to point out specific parts of the code that needs to be updated. If you need more information about global state, you can check [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)